# Backprop through Pytorch Element-Wise Operation if input contains NaNs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pytorch

Suppose I'd like to compute the element-wise quotient between two tensors. If one of the tensors contains NaNs, the resulting quotient will also contain NaNs, and this I understand. But why does the gradient becomes non-existent for the entire operation? And how can I preserve the gradient for the non-NaN entries?

For example:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1.0, np.NaN])
>>> y = torch.tensor([2.0, 3.0])
>>> z = torch.div(y, x)
>>> z
tensor([2., nan])
>>> z.backward()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 107, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 93, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code, which I hereby address, in hope to enlighten you :)

- `RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn` is NOT because of the `NaN`. It's because none of your input variables require a gradient, therefore z doesn't have the possibility to call `backward()`. You need to start the backpropagation tree somewhere.
- You can't just `.backward()` on a tensor with multiple values. You need to `sum()` first, or some similar operation, but that would produce `NaN` in your case. You can backpropagate both parts of the `z` separately, by calling `.backward(torch.Tensor([1.0,1.0]))`.

Therefore, if you fix all the bugs, it should work:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

x = torch.tensor([1.0, np.NaN], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0, 3.0])
z = torch.div(y, x)

z.backward(torch.Tensor([1.0,1.0]))
print(x.grad)
```

```
tensor([-2., nan])
```

Comment: I have another problem where I receive the following error: `RuntimeError: Function 'DivBackward0' returned nan values in its 0th output.` If I create another question, could you help me understand what I'm doing incorrectly there?

Comment: Sure, that's what this is for :)

Comment: Thanks :) Let me try to get a minimum viable example working.

Comment: my problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013705/runtimeerror-divbackward0-nan-values-in-its-0th-output-but-works-when-tensors

Comment: Can you take a look when you have ten minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small tweak:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
x = torch.tensor([1.0, np.NaN], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0, 3.0])
z = torch.div(y, x)
z #tensor([2., nan], grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)
```

In other words you need to say you require gradient calculation, else tensor will be without grad function.