# RuntimeError 'DivBackward0' nan values in its 0th output, but works when tensors loaded from disk?

Tags: python, python-3.6, pytorch

I'm trying to implement a particular loss function in PyTorch called [SMAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_mean_absolute_percentage_error) (commonly used in time series forecasting). I have two variables, `model_outputs` and `target_outputs`, and the formula for computing the element-wise SMAPE is straight-forward:

```
numerator = torch.abs(model_outputs - target_outputs)
denominator = torch.abs(model_outputs) + torch.abs(target_outputs)
elementwise_smape = torch.div(numerator, denominator)
nan_mask = torch.isnan(elementwise_smape)
loss = elementwise_smape[~nan_mask].mean()
assert ~torch.isnan(loss)  # loss = 0.023207199
loss.backward()
```

But when I ran my code, I received the following error: `RuntimeError: Function 'DivBackward0' returned nan values in its 0th output.`

I used `autograd.detect_anomaly()` to track down the error as stemming from `elementwise_smape = torch.div(numerator, denominator)`. I tried the suggested solutions I could find online (checking for NaN values, adding hooks, printing gradients) and nothing helped. So I decided to write the tensors to disk and write an independent script:

```
import torch


model_outputs = torch.load('model_outputs.pt')
target_outputs = torch.load('target_outputs.pt')
print(model_outputs)
print(target_outputs)

model_outputs.requires_grad = True
target_outputs.requires_grad = False

numerator = torch.abs(model_outputs - target_outputs)
denominator = torch.abs(model_outputs) + torch.abs(target_outputs)
elementwise_smape = torch.div(numerator, denominator)
nan_mask = torch.isnan(elementwise_smape)
loss = elementwise_smape[~nan_mask].mean()
assert ~torch.isnan(loss)
print(loss.detach().numpy())
loss.backward()
print('Success!')
```

This worked completely fine! To test that the problem doesn't originate from any of the variables `elementwise_smape` depends on (`model_outputs`, `numerator`, `denominator`), I tried replacing the loss function with each of the dependent variables, but all worked!

```
nan_mask = torch.isnan(elementwise_smape)
loss = model_outputs[~nan_mask].mean()
loss.backward()  # succeeds
```

```
nan_mask = torch.isnan(elementwise_smape)
loss = numerator[~nan_mask].mean()
loss.backward()  # succeeds
```

```
nan_mask = torch.isnan(elementwise_smape)
loss = denominator[~nan_mask].mean()
loss.backward()  # succeeds
```

So what the hell is going on with the element-wise division that causes a problem when `model_outputs` are generated by the model, but not when `model_outputs` are loaded from disk?

Update #1: Adding complete error:

```
Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/main.py", line 116, in <module>
    main(experiment_number)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/main.py", line 23, in main
    loss_per_model_per_step=loss_per_model_per_step)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/main.py", line 47, in run
    sequence_lengths)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/main.py", line 80, in step
    sequence_lengths=sequence_lengths)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/models.py", line 153, in loss
    model_output_log_probs=None)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/losses.py", line 96, in calculate_mean_smape
    target_outputs=target_outputs)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/losses.py", line 117, in calculate_elementwise_smape
    elementwise_smape = torch.div(numerator, denominator)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/main.py", line 116, in <module>
    main(experiment_number)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/main.py", line 23, in main
    loss_per_model_per_step=loss_per_model_per_step)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/main.py", line 47, in run
    sequence_lengths)
  File "/home/rylan/tsml/main.py", line 89, in step
    total_loss.backward()
  File "/home/rylan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 107, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "/home/rylan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 93, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: Function 'DivBackward0' returned nan values in its 0th output.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Update #2: Finomnis suggested writing the tensors to disk, reading them back and comparing them to the original:

```
torch.save(model_outputs, 'model_outputs.pt')
torch.save(target_outputs, 'target_outputs.pt')
model_outputs_2 = torch.load('model_outputs.pt')
target_outputs_2 = torch.load('target_outputs.pt')
(model_outputs == model_outputs_2).all()  # tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)
(target_outputs == target_outputs_2).all()  # tensor(0, dtype=torch.uint8)
```

I suspected that `(target_outputs == target_outputs_2).all()` evaluates to `False` due to `NaNs`. This is correct:

```
(torch.isnan(target_outputs) == torch.isnan(target_outputs_2)).all()  # tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)
(target_outputs[~torch.isnan(target_outputs)] == target_outputs_2[~torch.isnan(target_outputs_2)]).all()  # tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Update #3: I tried the next suggestion of detaching `model_outputs` to ensure that the problem isn't originating from elsewhere:

```
def calculate_elementwise_smape(model_outputs,
                                target_outputs):
    model_outputs = model_outputs.detach()
    model_outputs.requires_grad = True

    target_outputs = target_outputs.detach()

    numerator = torch.abs(model_outputs - target_outputs)
    denominator = torch.abs(model_outputs) + torch.abs(target_outputs)
    elementwise_smape = torch.div(numerator, denominator)
    return elementwise_smape
```

but this produced the same error `RuntimeError: Function 'DivBackward0' returned nan values in its 0th output.` at the same location `elementwise_smape = torch.div(numerator, denominator)`

To reiterate what I said earlier, this problem does not occur if I load the tensors from disk and make the exact same sequence of operations.

Comment: @Finomnis , any ideas?

Comment: Could you also add the full error+stacktrace?

Comment: Done! Let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Comment: Does `model_outputs.mean().backward()` and `target_outputs.mean().backward()` run without a problem?

Comment: `model_outputs.mean().backward()` runs fine. `target_outputs.mean().backward()` raises the error `RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn`, which makes sense as `target_outputs.requires_grad` is `False` (`target_outputs` is the supervised learning target).

Comment: Write the `model_outputs` and `target_outputs` to disk and read them again. Then compare the tensors before and after having them on the disk. What changed? I mean, the problem hides most likely in the details of those tensors, and having two of them that are very close but one works and one doesn't sound like it shouldn't be too hard to see the difference.

Comment: `model_outputs` is equal to itself after being written to and read from disk. `target_outputs` is also equal to itself .

Comment: Since `target_outputs` contains NaNs and since NaN != NaN, I checked both whether the NaN indices are the same and whether the non-NaN values are the same. Both are true.

Comment: Are they also the same type? Next try... do `model_outputs = model_outputs.detach()`, followed by `model_outputs.requires_grad=True` and `target_outputs = target_outputs.detach()`. This is to decouple them from everything that came earlier, just to make sure the error doesn't originate from somewhere completely different. Then run the entire algorithm on those two tensors.

Comment: Good suggestion, but the same problem remains: `RuntimeError: Function 'DivBackward0' returned nan values in its 0th output.` I can add an update to the above question if you want to see the complete code.

Comment: Happy to chat if faster :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196398/discussion-between-finomnis-and-rylan-schaeffer).